# Make a phone call In Windows 10 mobile

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I writing app for Windows 10 Mobile

I need to call Phone Task, when I tap a button.

I try to do it like this

```
 private void TelephoneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask
        {
            PhoneNumber = "+380442308888",
            DisplayName = "The Name goes here"
        };

        phoneCallTask.Show();

    }
```

and using this `using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;`

But I have this error in using
`Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Phone' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

and this in `PhoneCallTask`

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'PhoneCallTask' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What's wrong and how I can call Phone Task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [PhoneCallManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phonecallmanager). A reference is needed to [Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn706155.aspx).

Then you could do something like this:

```
private void TelephoneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI("+380442308888", "The Name goes here");
}
```

Update add a reference
[image]

Comment: What reference I need to add?

Comment: Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract

Comment: like this  
using Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract ;??

Comment: Yes do that and then Visual Studio will suggest to add that assembly for you if you have not done it already.

Comment: I have only Collections, Metadata and Diagnostics

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Check the update, right click on Reference and click add reference and search for Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract